# Set UiTextField cursor on top Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield, cursor

I have a TextField in my storyboard with a height of 100 .

When I'm clicking the TextField the cursor is placed in center :

[image]

I would like to set the cursor position **in the top left corner**.

I tried :

```
let startPosition: UITextPosition = textField.beginningOfDocument
```

But it seems that the position is already at the beginning and when the height is extended the cursor stay in center.

How can it be done ?

Comment: You should consider using UITextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want a multiline UITextField. In that case you might want to take a look at UITextView, which should allow for what you want ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview))